# change the name of the input fields into array on Appendgrid

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I wanna ask about how to change the input name in the `appendgrid`
[image]

as on the image above i have the select input as `Sub Program` which the name is `tblAppendGrid_subprogram_1` and below the input the name of the input field is `tblAppendGrid_subprogram_2`.

With the case above I wanna ask about how to change the names of the input  fields into `tblAppendGrid_subprogram[]`

some codes of the `Appendgrid` below

```
 $(function() {
      $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
        caption: 'Detail Penerimaan dana',
        maxRowsAllowed: 3,
        initRows: 1,
        columns: [
          { name: 'subprogram', display: 'Sub Program', type: 'select',
          ctrlOptions:
              <?php echo $subprogram;?>
          ,ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '100%'},ctrlClass: 'form-control' },
          { name: 'sumberdana', display: 'Sumber Dana', type: 'select',
          ctrlOptions:
              <?php echo $sumberdana;?>
          ,ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '100%'},ctrlClass: 'form-control' } ,
          { name: 'kategori', display: 'Kategori', type: 'select',
          ctrlOptions:
              <?php echo $kategori;?>
          ,ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '100%'},ctrlClass: 'form-control' },
          { name: 'jumlah', display: 'Jumlah',ctrlClass: 'form-control' },
          { name: 'catatan', display: 'Catatan',ctrlClass: 'form-control' }
        ],
        hideButtons: { moveUp: true, moveDown: true }

      });
    });
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can use this code to set input fields into array on Appendgrid

```
 nameFormatter: function (idPrefix, name, uniqueIndex) {
            return  name+'[]';
 }
```

example:

```
$('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
                caption: 'Detail Penerimaan dana',
                nameFormatter: function (idPrefix, name, uniqueIndex) 
 {
                return  name+'[]';
 }});
```

Comment: Thank you it works now the name of the fields have changed into array